# ¿Insert en 2 tablas distintas laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Quiero hacer un insert en 2 tablas distintas de la base de datos. Tengo la tabla vacaciones que guarda las vacaciones y tengo un calendario, en el que deben guardarse los eventos del calendario para mostrarlo cada vez que se aprueben unas vacaciones, entonces tengo:

**Metodo del controlador:** En el cual guardo en vacaciones si se aprueba o no las vacaciones, y intento llamar al otro modelo, para insertar en la tabla calendario eventos.

```
$vacation=new Vacation();
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $vacation = Vacation::find($request['id']);
    $vacation-> aceptado = '1';
    $vacation->save();

    $evento = new CalendarioEvento;
    $evento -> fechaIni = $vacation['date_from'];
    $evento -> fechaFin = $vacation['date_to'];
    $evento -> todoeldia = true;
    $evento -> color = 'rgb(244, 67, 54)';
    $evento -> titulo = $vacation['type'];
    $vacation-> evento()->save($evento);

    return redirect('/vacation/request');
```

**Modelo:**

```
class CalendarioEvento extends Model{
   public function vacation(){
      $this->belongsTo('App\Vacation');
   }
}


class Vacation extends Model{
   public function evento()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\CalendarioEvento');
   }
}
```

y el error que me da es:

```
    QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vacation_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `calendario_eventos` (`fechaIni`, `fechaFin`, `todoeldia`, `color`, `titulo`, `vacation_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , 1, rgb(244, 67, 54), , 2, 2018-02-20 11:58:06, 2018-02-20 11:58:06))
```

Con lo cual entiendo que cuando añado la parte del método que añade los eventos del calendario busca el `id` de vacaciones (que no tiene que buscar), en la tabla que no tiene que buscar, ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto para hacer el `insert` en la segunda tabla después de realizar el primer `update`?

Comment: puedes mostrar la tabla `calendario_eventos`, si esta relacionada con `vacations` debe tener un identificador `vacation_id` pero al parecer no lo tiene, ene ese caso debes decirle con que campo hacer la relación

Comment: Realmente no necesito relación entre las tablas, es simplemente insertar parte de los datos para visualizarlo, pero bueno, he acabado por crear el campo vacation_id, para evitar problemas. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Para poder utilizar `$vacation-> evento()->save($evento)` es necesaria una relación entre los modelos, de ser así lo que intentas hacer es muy distinto a lo que hace dicha sintaxis. ¿Simplemente intentas guardar dos modelos y ya? Te invito a revisar entonces la documentación de Laravel para que veas lo que hace el método que intentas utilizar sin necesidad: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no necesitas relación entre las tablas (tal y como lo explicas en los comentarios), simplemente puedes usar el método `save()` en cada uno de ellos (por aparte) o puedes usar `firstOrCreate()` o `updateOrCreate()` o `create()` para el nuevo modelo.

```
// Las tres primeras líneas no son necesarias, se pueden reemplazar con Route Model Binding

$vacation=new Vacation();
$id = $request->get('id');
$vacation = Vacation::find($request['id']);

$vacation-> aceptado = '1';
$vacation->save();

$evento = new CalendarioEvento;
$evento -> fechaIni = $vacation['date_from'];
$evento -> fechaFin = $vacation['date_to'];
$evento -> todoeldia = true;
$evento -> color = 'rgb(244, 67, 54)';
$evento -> titulo = $vacation['type'];
$vacation->save();
```

o con el método `create()` para CalendarioEvento, pasando un array con los valores de los campos:

```
$evento = CalendarioEvento::create([
    'fechaIni' => $vacation['date_from'],
    'fechaFin' => $vacation['date_to'],
    ....
]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Shaz, lo he conseguido solucionar, cabe destacar que en vez de $request para mandarle los datos he de usar la variable $vacation que es la que tiene los parametros que necesito a insertar, lo necesito por si alquien viene con un problema parecido, y edito mi pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Lo he modificado también, me surge una duda entonces: ¿algún motivo en particular para no utilizar la sintaxis de objetos? Estás usando `$vacation['date_from']` y no `$vacation->date_from`

Comment: Pues la verdad, desconocimiento mas bien, soy relativamente nuevo trabajando con laravel, y no tengo muy clara la sintaxis, entre que he tenido que aprender javascript html css y php, súmale la sintaxis de laravel, y hay tienes la respuesta jeje, pero gracias por la corrección, si es la mejor manera de programarlo así lo hare :)